# How do I add keyboard shortcuts in SSMS 2012 to run a specific query?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I add keyboard shortcuts in SSMS 2012 to select all the data from table?

In SSMS 2008 we could assign a shortcut in the following way:

> TOOLS-->OPTIONS-->ENVIRONMENT-->KEYBOARD--->CTRL+3-->Select * from

This doesn't appear to be possible in SSMS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

The option is still there (although this is from SQL Server 2014):

[image]

You don't normally have to restart SSMS, just open a new query window.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [this Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/737453/sql-server-management-studio-2012-ctrl-f1-launches-help-not-query-shortcut-code), there is a comment (on a slightly unrelated problem) suggesting that you need to restart SQL Server Management Studio before any changes to the Keyboard Shortcuts take place

> Posted by jaredaz on 28/08/2012 at 14:13
>
> This problem seems to go away after restarting management studio
>   (where in prior versions it would begin working in a new query).

Having attempted to replicate this, I can confirm that the shortcut does not work until I restart SSMS, however after a restart I can run `SELECT * FROM <table>` from Ctrl+3.